# prevent task pane from closing during saving (async)

Tags: office-js, outlook-web-addins

We use the OfficeJs REST API for add-in development.
To use this API, an accesstoken is needed, which we request by invoking `Office.mailbox.getCallbackTokenAsync({ isRest: true })`
during startup of our add-in.

This does not fail for any code triggered by the onSend function: It seems OfficeJs saves the mail item before onSend code is triggered.

However, this request apparently *does fail* when the mail item is *not yet saved* - which is the case for any new draft when it is just created - and thus breaks the init code of our add-in when the task pane is opened straight after composing a new message.

To remedy that, one can call `Office.messageCompose.saveAsync`.
This however causes the task pane to disappear as the current mail item is refreshed (hypothesis).

Is there anything that we can do to prevent the task pane from being closed after calling `saveAsync` or retrieve the REST access token without having to save the mail item first ?

Comment: Are you seeing this in all Outlook clients? Could you share the build number for the version you are using? 

We've been unable to reproduce the taskpane closing when the saveAsync OfficeJS API is called on a message draft in Outlook online or Outlook Desktop for Windows.Could you share your code snippet as well?

Comment: Sorry I should have been more specific: we currently only develop our add-in for the Outlook Web App for Office365, requirement set 1.5 (moving to 1.6 soon). Not sure if I can give you a build number, where could I find that? code snippet: https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-v3wcs5 the code snippet is devoid of Angular / NGRX references but captures the gist of what we're trying to do, specifically, the code in `someEffectCodeRunOnInit`.

Comment: I am now not sure if it is really actually saving the item that is triggering the closing of the add-in, because manually saving the draft before opening the add-in does not prevent the automatic closing. However, the example snippet is really the point where this happens: when `getCallbackTokenAsync` + the `saveAsync` call are removed, the add-in stays open :(

Comment: Have you been able to reproduce this ?

Comment: We are not able to reproduce the issue. Tried calling saveAsync and within it's callback called getCallbackTokenAsync and we get the token back as expected. What browser are you seeing this behavior on? Does it happen on all browsers?

Comment: We can consistently reproduce this in `OSX Safari 11.1.1 (12605.2.8)`, `OSX Firefox 60.0.1 (64-bit)`, `OSX Chrome 67.0.3396.62`. We have not been able to reproduce this in `OSX Opera 53.0.2907.68`. Strange thing we noticed is that in firefox, this only is reproducible the first time after logging in on OWA, creating a draft, and opening our add-in. after that, creating new drafts and opening our add-in right away did not show this behaviour.

Comment: We can not reproduce this in BrowserStack using both the latest `IE 11` and `Edge 17`.

Comment: We tried OSX Safari 11.1.1 (13605.2.8), OSX Chrome 67.0.3396.62 but were not able to reproduce the issue either. Could you create a simple add-in that just does the below and check if the issue reproduces. If it does, give us the manifest and we can try to see whats going on. What you would need to do in the app is simply call saveasync and within its callback call gettoken with isRest as true and see if the issue reproduces.

Comment: This is what we used: /* Click Run Code to save an item async */

//Save an item async
Office.context.mailbox.item.saveAsync
(
 function(asyncResult)
 {
  var options = {
       isRest: true,
   asyncContext: { message: 'Hello World!' }
  };

  Office.context.mailbox.getCallbackTokenAsync(options, function(asyncResult) {
   showMessage(JSON.stringify(result));
  });
 }
);
Create a simple addin with this and see if that ends up closing the taskpane for you too?

Comment: Hi, sorry for the delay. we are indeed still able to reproduce this problem with your code. see here for a screenshot of what we run: https://imgur.com/a/Lu9c78L
and here a video of the behaviour that we are seeing: https://imgur.com/KaZrKsS

Comment: Got it. I can now reproduce this problem. To check that I have the complete picture, if I start composing the email (select 'New') when the 'Drafts' folder is selected, the addin closes on the saveAsync call.  However, the addin stays open if I do the same in another folder (for example 'Inbox'). Is that what you are seeing also?

Comment: oh wow, indeed, you are correct. I did not even realise this was the case. It appears that only when in the `drafts` folder this happens.

Comment: Great, thank you confirming the bug. We are working on a fix as quickly as we can.

Comment: Great news! Might you have a (public) issue tracker we can use to follow progress ?

Comment: What is the status on this issue? It is still occurring and quite annoying

Comment: Apologies for the delay. As you might have seen recently, [the new version of Outlook Web](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/Outlook-Blog/An-early-version-of-the-new-Outlook-on-the-web-will-be-available/ba-p/225338) is now available to opt into. This bug has been fixed in the new version of Outlook.

Comment: Hi. We indeed noticed this was fixed, thank you. If you can add this as answer, I'll mark it as such.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To avoid the issue of the Task Pane closing, please use [the new version of Outlook Web](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/Outlook-Blog/An-early-version-of-the-new-Outlook-on-the-web-will-be-available/ba-p/225338). The bug has been fixed in this version of Outlook.