# Reply form opened by mailbox.item.displayReplyAllForm collapsed by default

Tags: outlook-addin, office-js, outlook-web-app

(or opened from `mailbox.item.displayReplyForm`)

Is this because you are not allowed or not able to switch to `compose mode` from `read mode` immediately?

It seems rather... dull that we can trigger a reply, but can not have it open automatically :/

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by 'open automatically'? Also what version/browser/client are you testing the API in?

Comment: I mean *not* collapsed. I mean that users should be able to work on their draft straight away without first having to click the edit button (which also closes a pinned task pane, by the way... but that is another bug for another time)

`Outlook Web App` (full, not light)  / `Chrome 68.0.3440.106` / `OSX 10.12.6`

Comment: I can't reverse engineer where I can find the OWA version number...
This guide:
https://support.office.com/en-us/article/options-outlook-web-app-version-38db0be3-8d63-499f-9c34-cdb3bf83d8fd
mentions this path: `Settings > Options > Display settings > Outlook Web App version` which doesn't work, because I don't have `Options` in my `Settings` menu.

Comment: Can you please provide a screenshot of what you are seeing? The API should open a reply form in a pop-up dialog that allows the user to edit the form.

Comment: on Chrome it does no such thing. It creates a reply right above the mail item, which is closed: https://imgur.com/RQWOifv.

Comment: Similarly, `Office.UI.displayDialogAsync` álso does not open in a popup (or Iframe) on chrome, as it should, but as a new tab : https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js-docs/blob/master/reference/shared/officeui.displaydialogasync.md
This might be related.
Since the latter is not detrimental to our user experience, we never reported that (and also because you have no public bug tracker whatsoever so we can't track when it would be resolved. Just like we can't track the bug reported in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50565850/prevent-task-pane-from-closing-during-saving-async at all).

Comment: If a pop-up blocker is enabled, the fallback is the screenshot that you linked. If there is no pop-up blocker, then it should pop out.

Comment: For displayDialogAsync you can try playing around with displayInIframe to see if the different behaviors meet your needs.

Comment: aha, that makes a lot of sense... I'll check if this is the cause, it probably is.
Still, it does not explain (in case someone has a popup blocker active) why the inserted reply appears as closed / collapsed?